# Dramatic voltage drop issue

Tags: circuit-design, voltage

I'm using this circuit design:

[image: Schematic from EEVblog forum]

<sub>[Link to original project page with schematic on EEVblog forum](https://www.eevblog.com/forum/projects/simple-discrete-two-transistor-boost-converter/)</sub>

I changed some values:

- R1:220 ohms
- R3:470 ohms
- C1:470pF
- M1: TIP41C.

When I turn the converter on and connect a 500mA load, the output voltage significantly drops from 5.6V to 4.6V, and there is a voltage drop across my inductor.

Is there any fault on my side? I used every other thing of same value except the components above.

Is my inductor saturating? I'm getting 0.07V drop across it, which is odd.

Any ideas what is going on?

(By the way, I'm stepping up 3.7V to 5V for LED strip. I like discrete.)

Comment: Chipresistor122 - Hi, To prevent the people here from wasting their time repeating previous advice, I think it would be helpful to give links to where you have already asked your question and got (at least partially) similar replies on [Electro-Tech-Online.com](https://www.electro-tech-online.com/threads/discrete-boost-converter-output-voltage-drop.160158/) and [All About Circuits](https://forum.allaboutcircuits.com/threads/voltage-drops-on-this-switcher-everywhere.173919/). Why are you asking *again*? (I also found the working link for the image, so I've fixed that in the question for you.)

Comment: 0.07V isn't a very big drop. Do you have an oscilloscope?

Answer (score 1):

Is it intended that R3 be changed from 70k to 470? That's a pretty big difference.
I also can't tell if the TIP41C is workable or not because I can't find any information on BSZ0920NS. I see from comments that BSZ0920NS is a mosfet and TIP41C which I did find on digikey, is a regular NPN transistor. I'm not sure they will fill the same role since mosfets work a little differently.